# How to stop a "setInterval" and start a other with the same FUNCTION

Tags: javascript, setinterval

i realy need your help. I have a chat with diferent rooms. When the user click on a ROOM BUTTON it appears the messages tha has on that room, and updates with a SetINTERVAL every 2 sec.

EXAMPELE CODE:

```
var abc = setInterval(function()
    { 
        $.ajax({
          type:"post",
          url:"logs.php?user_profil=<?php echo $user_profil;?>&user=<?php echo $user;?>",
          datatype:"html",
          success:function(data)
          {
             $("#chatlogs").html(data);
          }
        });
    }, 2000);
```

The problem is that if hi clicks on a other ROOM BUTTON the chats overlap.
how can i stop the

**VAR ABC**  and start it again with different values?

[HERE IS A EXAMPLE(this is just a example page):](http://www.informfan.com/EXAMPLE/ajax/includes/chat_profil_personal.php)

Comment: I put the answer below, but you should seriously consider websockets for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
var myMethod = function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "logs.php?user_profil=<?php echo $user_profil;?>&user=<?php echo $user;?>",
      datatype: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#chatlogs").html(data);
      }
    });
  },
  abc = setInterval(myMethod, 2000);

clearInterval(abc);
abc = setInterval(myMethod, 2000);
```

Explanation: save the callback method into a variable and re-use that variable for setInterval;

Comment: The correct way to cancel a timer is to use `clearInterval(abc)`.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i stop the VAR ABC and start it again with different values

By the way, the `abc` variable just holds id of that particular interval. You realy don't need (and you can't) to "start it again", you need to start *another* one :).

I would do it like this:

```
var getRoomUpdater = (function(){
    var _userProfileId;
    var updater = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "logs.php?user_profil=" + _userProfileId + "&user=<?php echo $user;?>",
            datatype: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#chatlogs").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    return function(userProfileId){
        _userProfileId = userProfileId;
        return updater;
    };
})();

// it will hold interval id
var abc;


// Opening a room:
var openRoom = function(roomId){
    // start automatic update
    clearInterval(abc);
    abc = setInterval(getRoomUpdater(roomId));


    // + other actions if needed
}
```